# Materialized views use older dbms_job instead of scheduler?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

Very new to this topic - using 11g.

When I create a materialized view, a matching job (not a scheduler job) is created.  But it's my understanding that `dbms_job` is being replaced by `dbms_scheduler`.

Am I doing something wrong or am I totally misunderstanding what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong and your understanding is correct.  Materialized views that are created or altered to have a refresh schedule use `DBMS_JOB` rather than `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.  This would be unexpected given the following wording from the [11.2 Administrators Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/appendix_a001.htm#BGBFBIHF) (emphasis mine):

> DBMS_JOB is a PL/SQL package that you use to schedule jobs. **It is
>   replaced** by Oracle Scheduler, which is more powerful and flexible.
>   Although Oracle recommends that you switch from DBMS_JOB to Oracle
>   Scheduler, DBMS_JOB is **still supported for backward compatibility**.

I agree with Jack Douglas and the comments he linked to.  `DBMS_JOB` is unlikely to go away anytime soon.

Comment: Leigh, I'm not sure that I'd read the extract in the same way as you. In prior versions scheduled MVIEW refreshes were accomplished by creating a dbms_job. I would not expect that code to be removed from the oracle kernel because dbms_scheduler was created. I'd say that fell under the backward compatibility banner.

Comment: You may be correct.  Oracle's statement isn't quite as strong as their statment on LONGs for example: `Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward compatibility.`  That being said, it would go against the conventional meaning of `replaced` and `still supported for backward compatibility` to not remove it at some point.

Comment: In your opinion should I leave the job as is or replace it with a manually created dbms_scheduler job that does a refresh?

Comment: @engil Leave it.  The feature hasn't been removed yet and if/when it gets removed you can change it as part of the migration process.  In the end you may never have to do this and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

`dbms_scheduler`, while being much more powerful/flexible than `dbms_job`, [is not a simple/complete replacement](http://orastory.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/in-support-of-dbms_job/) for it. `dbms_job` is still widely used as you have discovered and [is unlikely to go away](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:25405608521707#2323186400346063349)

Answer (score 0):

It seams that in Oracle Release 19.3 a `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job is created for a MV with `start with ... next`

```
select JOB_NAME, JOB_ACTION from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS;

JOB_NAME             JOB_ACTION                              
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
MV_RF$J_0_S_2932     dbms_refresh.refresh('"LAB"."SIM_JOB"');
```

The *refresh group*  is created in the same way, but the `JOB` is zero and the `JOB_NAME` is populated pointing in `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS`.

```
select owner, name, rname, REFGROUP, job,JOB_NAME, interval, next_date 
from DBA_REFRESH_CHILDREN;
```